# Getting Error 'Document update conflict' with PouchDB

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I created a service on Ionic Project. While online it will get the data from API, save the data on PouchDB and return the data.

While offline it will just get the data from pouchDB.

But I can't update the data on PouchDB, return the message: 'Document update conflict', Status 409.

I will insert here some code..

```
lista.forEach(element => {
    if (element) {
      inserirBanco.push({
        _id: `hist_transacao_${element.codigo}_${element.codigofidelidade}`,
        oidEvento: element.oidEvento,
        codigo: element.codigo,
        codigofidelidade: element.codigofidelidade,
        codigofidelidadelote: element.codigofidelidadelote,
        datarequisicao: element.datarequisicao,
        datasorteio: element.datasorteio,
        latitude: element.latitude,
        longitude: element.longitude,
        nomeevento: element.nomeevento,
        quantidadetitulo: element.quantidadetitulo,
        situacao: element.situacao,
        titulofinal: element.titulofinal,
        tituloinicial: element.tituloinicial,
        tipo_registro: 'transacoes-vendas-com-historico'
      });
    }
  });
}

if (inserirBanco.length > 0) {
  this.getRevData(inserirBanco).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('beforeBulk');
    console.log(res);
    res.forEach((obj) => {
      this._db.put(obj);
    });
  })
}
```

getRevData function

```
private getRevData(list: Array<any>): Observable<Array<any>> {
return new Observable(observer => {

  this._db.allDocs( (listaDocs) => {
    if(listaDocs){

      listaDocs.forEach((item) => {
        list.forEach((itemActual) => {
          if(itemActual._id === item._id) {
            itemActual._rev = item._rev;
          }
        });
      });

    }
  });

  observer.next(list);
  observer.complete();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code to:

```
if (inserirBanco.length > 0) {
  inserirBanco.forEach((obj) => {
    this._db.getId(obj._id)
      .then(registro => {
        this._db.delete(registro).then(() => {
          this._db.add(obj);
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        this._db.add(obj);
    });
  });
}
```

and It works.